# How to set working directory when debugging VB6 app?

Tags: vb6

I am debugging a VB6 executable. The executable loads dlls and files from it's current directory, when running. When run in debugger, the current directory seems to be VB6's dir.

How do I set working directory for VB6?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't seems to be a "out of the box" solution for this thing.

Taken from [The Old Joel On Software Forums](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware1/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=19026&ixReplies=5)

> Anyways.. to put this topic to rest..
>   the following was my VB6 solution:  I
>   define 2 symbols in my VB project
>   "MPDEBUG" and "MPRELEASE" and call the
>   following function as the first
>   operation in my apps entry point
>   function.

```
Public Sub ChangeDirToApp()
#If MPDEBUG = 0 And MPRELEASE = 1 Then
  ' assume that in final release builds the current dir will be the location
  ' of where the .exe was installed; paths are relative to the install dir
  ChDrive App.path
  ChDir App.path
#Else
  ' in all debug/IDE related builds, we need to switch to the "bin" dir
  ChDrive App.path
  ChDir App.path & BackSlash(App.path) & "..\bin"
#End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

Solution that I have found that works uses a `Sub Main`, and checks if the program is running in the IDE.

```
Dim gISIDE as Boolean

Sub Main()
    If IsIDE Then
        ChDrive App.Path
        ChDir   App.Path
    End If

    ' The rest of the code goes here...

End Sub

Public Function IsIDE() As Boolean '
        IsIDE = False
        'This line is only executed if running in the IDE and then returns True
        Debug.Assert CheckIDE 
        If gISIDE Then 
            IsIDE = True
        End If
End Function

Private Function CheckIDE() As Boolean ' this is a helper function for Public Function IsIDE() 
        gISIDE = True 'set global flag 
        CheckIDE = True 
End Function
```

Answer (score 8):

"The current directory seems to be VB6's dir" only when you open a project using File-Open.

Open it by double clicking the .vbp file while having the IDE closed.

Answer (score 1):

[Will this work?](http://sintaks.blogspot.com/2006/07/vb6-set-current-working-directory.html)

```
'Declaration
Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectory Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "SetCurrentDirectoryA" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long

'syntax to set current dir
SetCurrentDirectory App.Path
```

Comment: But it is simpler to use the native VB6 commands `ChDrive App.Path: ChDir App.Path`

Comment: Why use this instead of the built in functions?

Answer (score 1):

Current directory for any program - including vb6 - can be changed in the properties of the shortcut. I've changed it to the root of my source tree, it makes using File-Open quicker.