# FileSystemObject - default location

Tags: vb6

When I debug my application (in the VB6 IDE), I have to specify the absolute path (e.g. `c:\logfile.log`) to the log file otherwise nothing is written to the log file.  However, when the application is live I do not have to specify the absolute path i.e. I can specify `logfile.log`.  Why is this?

The log file is always in the same directory as the .exe and .dll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set working directory when debugging VB6 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154299/how-to-set-working-directory-when-debugging-vb6-app)

Answer (score 1):

Your file is being written to the current working directory.

When your exe is running this is the folder the exe is sat in, however in Debug mode your exe is actually running from the temporary build location (can't actually remember where this is in VB6).

You can test this simply by doing `MsgBox(App.Path)` in your program and seeing what location appears.

You'll probably find that there is a `logfile.log` in the location that appears when you run the above command while debugging.

Comment: Thanks.  App.Path appears to be the working directory of my application (in debugging mode).  This is not the file it is writing to.

Comment: Not quite, the working directory will be whatever the app that started it passes. Sometimes it will happen to be the EXE folder (when run from Explorer). See the `CurDir()` for the current path. Using App.Path gives you the path to the exe but is NOT writable by default.

Comment: I think the GUI Shell in Windows has lead people away from the understanding of CD most of us gained in the DOS days. I suspect that App.Path has replaced the concept in VB6 programmer's minds, since in so many cases they at least start out at the same path. However a program shortcut can set this ("Start in") path too.  Or use of a CommonDialog may alter it during execution.