# UAC now required on a VB6 project that didn't have it before

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2008-r2, uac

I had a VB6 project that did not previously require UAC on Server 2008 R2.  My most recent builds have the little UAC (User Access Control) icon on the program icon.  When I try to open the app, Windows prompts for administrative rights.

The only changes I made were to where the application looks for its settings file.  Previously, these files were anchored to a static location in `C:\app\`.  Since I prefer the .NET style of having the settings in with the app, I made the code first look locally using `App.Path`, then look at the previous static location if no file exists locally.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that `App.Path` was determined to be the cause of the UAC prompt.  I commented out the one line of code and the shield icon went away.  It seems that heuristics for UAC assumed that I would be writing to the `Program Files` folder.

The code was only reading a file, and `ForReaading` was specified when using `FileSytemObject`'s `OpenTextFile` method.

**MY ALTERNATIVE**

`CurDir` seems to work for me, since the file is only read at startup.  The one caveat is that while debugging, `CurDir` is set to the IDE's exe path.  It works fine when the app is compiled.

However, if you open the project by opening the `.vbp` file (double-click, e.g.) directly in the folder, `CurDir` will be correct.  It's only the IDE's exe path when you first open the IDE and then open the project from within the IDE.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/154595/2084315

Comment: There's no heuristics here. `App.Path` is based on where your application is located (installed), and you've apparently installed it in a UAC-defended location such as Program Files. Of course, you could always use a message box to find out where `App.Path` is located.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I did try the manifest - it opened without UAC, but UAC immediately returned an error saying that elevated permissions were required.

Comment: @KenWhite - the app was located in `D:\AppName\AppName.exe`;  it's not installed, either-- just a portable executable.

Comment: Then UAC shouldn't have offered the prompt based just on the change to `App.Path`. There's something else going on, and your solution isn't correct. There should be no issue with accessing that folder, unless you've set some non-typical access rights to it.

Comment: @KenWhite - `App.Path` was the only thing I removed, and the UAC prompt is gone.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: If the app has a manifest, virtualization doesn't apply, and if virtualization was being used there wouldn't be a UAC prompt. I have a legacy app that still tries to write to an INI file in the Windows folder, so I'm pretty clear on how virtualization works; I'm always having to work with the file in VirtualStore. :-) It's a third-party app I have no control over, so I can't fix it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - The error message I see with `App.path` in the code and a manifest file saying that no elevated permissions are required is `The requested operation requires elevation.`  Both the prompt and the error go away when I take `App.Path` out of the code.  This will never be run from the command line, so no worries there.  My goal was to avoid the need to require elevation, since the app did not require it in previous builds.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I have a windows 8.1 Pro machine and I don't get the same issue, probably because my UAC setting is low (not off, though).  This happens on a Server 2008 machine where I am not an admin, but there are no new process that I can see, and the app doesn't even load.  You can probably replicate it by creating a manifest that says you don't need elevated privileges, then do something that requires elevation.  I haven't done a lot of work in VB6, but in .NET it was as simple as modifying a registry key for the local machine, and running that code as a non-admin.

Comment: Since the `App.Path` was used during app load, it should have been invoked before any of my forms were loaded.

Comment: Sounds like I misunderstood the scenario.  Sorry for the distraction, guys.